# why is flutter BottomAppBar transferring gestures to the scaffold body when extendBody is true?

Tags: flutter

Not sure if this is a bug or if it's meant to behave like this but here is the code to reproduce this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,      
      
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            print('tapped');
          },
          child: Container(color: Colors.red))
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){}),
       floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: const BottomAppBar(
          shape:  CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        notchMargin: 10,
        child: SizedBox(height: 100),
        
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I could possibly use a stack in the body and add a transparent container but just seems pointless. Why would the bar transfer gestures to the scaffold body?

Comment: Your Question is not Clear

Comment: if you tap the BottomAppBar and there is a widget behind it which can respond to gestures, these are being transferred. A non-gesture widget on top of a button etc. shouldn't transfer gestures as far as I can tell

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the bottom nav bar in an [AbsorbPointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html) widget to prevent this from happening:

```
BottomAppBar(
          shape:  CircularNotchedRectangle(),
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          notchMargin: 10,
          child: SizedBox(height: 100),
        ),
```

As you noticed, doing this makes the bottom bar useless. Instead, you need to add a widget that can recognize taps or gestures to the bottom bar:

```
BottomAppBar(
        elevation: 4,
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        notchMargin: 10,

        child: SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          child: TextButton(child: Text('Submit'),onPressed: (){debugPrint('test');},),
        ),
      ),
```

The key here is adding *something* to the bottomNavigationBar (not an empty SizedBox or Container).

Comment: I should have mentioned, I tried this - it totally renders the bottom bar useless. So if you have nav items, they won't work anymore.